# Using highcharts, how would I highlight only the intersection of 2 plotbands on the x and y axis?

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng, angular2-highcharts

I am using highcharts to display an inverted columnrange chart. The user can select both the x and y axis labels, which will use plotbands to highlight that entire row or column. My next step is, if the user highlights a row and then selects column headers to highlight the columns, I would only want the 'cells' where those plotbands intersect to be highlighted. Can I do this using only plotbands or will I need introduce other highcharts features to achieve this. (I saw some info around using render.rect() or possibly zones?)[image]

Comment: You cannot use plot bands for this. Zones might work but it might require fake points/series. I think the cleanest way is to render the rect with the [renderer.rect()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect).